# AttributeError: module 'cupy' has no attribute 'array'

Tags: python, python-3.x, cupy

I have just installed cupy v-6 on Win-10 using conda `conda install -c anaconda cupy` and the installation was going smoothly, my cuda version is 10.1, Python 3.7.4,

when I ran the following code, I get the error: `AttributeError: module 'cupy' has no attribute 'array'`

print dir result:

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'cp', 'np']
```

**Edit:**

Full Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\code\cupy.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cupy as cp
  File "D:\code\cupy.py", line 4, in <module>
    x_gpu = cp.array([1, 2, 3])
AttributeError: module 'cupy' has no attribute 'array'`
The code:
```

**My code**

```
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp

x_gpu = cp.array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: can you show full error

Comment: @Kalana yes sure.

Comment: Same here. I actually just run **python** from **terminal** **ONLY**, and tested your 3 lines of code, got the same **ERROR**:  **AttributeError: module 'cupy' has no attribute 'array'`**. Did you find the solutions???

Comment: @PeiJIA "*Did you find the solutions?*", yes, see the answer down, it works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your file name shouldn't be the same name as `cupy`. Therefore rename your file name and run again the code.

because, when you try to `import cupy`, it calls your `cupy.py` file instead of your `cupy` library. That's the reason your code didn't work